# Fine uploader request not working from vb6

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am using below Policy format and creating a application/json format with policy base 64 and signature sha base 64 but getting

> "Error attempting to parse signature response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token s"

Can you suggest where I am wrong:

```
strToPolicy = "{
    ""expiration"": ""2015-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"", 
    ""conditions"": [ 
        {""bucket"": manishtests3.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com }, 
        {""acl"": ""public-read"" },
        {""key"": my access key id},
        {""x-amz-meta-qqfilename"": Search.png},
    ]
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your policy appears to simply be malformed JSON... Take note of the formatting below:

```
{
    "conditions": [
        {
            "bucket": "manishtests3.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
        },
        {
            "acl": "public-read"
        },
        {
            "key": "my access key id"
        },
        {
            "x-amz-meta-qqfilename": "Search.png"
        }
    ],
    "expiration": "2015-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"
}
```

For more information there is also a specific [example of Amazon S3 Policy Format](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/08/16/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser/#policy-format) with regard to leveraging Fine Uploader and Amazon S3.

Comment: After that I am getting this response: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mytestupload.s3.amazonaws.com/. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Comment: After that I am getting this response: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://manishtests3.s3.amazonaws.com/. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect). I just change endpoint as it was saying 404 error so I changed it out to manishtests3.s3.amazonaws.com. Now its saying above.

Comment: This looks to be an error response to a cross-origin request. Are you certain that you've properly setup [CORS configuration](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/08/16/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser/#basic-cors-config) within your S3 bucket?